# SonarQube blame information for Jazz RTC contains comma in username

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, ibm-jazz

I am attempting to connect a new SonarQube (5.6 LTS) instance to my client's Jazz repository (with version 1.1 of the Jazz plugin) and have run into an interesting snag.  The Jazz users are connected using the corporate AD and the usernames returned by RTC's lscm annotate command is in the form of "lastname, firstname" so the result looks like:

`9   Smith, John        (1000) 2014-04-03 04:32 PM 272   some code here;`

The issue comes up when trying to tie this to a user in Sonar.  I cannot add the scm account "Smith, John" through the UI (it turns it into two accounts "Smith" and "John").  Also, the issue search fails to deal well with the comma so you can't go to the issue page and just filter by author = 'smith, john'.

I have to believe I'm not the first person to come across this issue but I've been unable to find any solutions online.  There are a couple of workarounds that I may end up trying but would prefer it if I didn't have to stray far from a plain OOTB SonarQube install.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this for the moment in SonarQube, but I've created a ticket to handle this : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7907

Comment: Thanks!  For now I ended up modifying the version of the RTC plugin that is used so that it moves the names back to "first last" order when reporting blame info.  It's an ugly hack, IMO, but gets the job done